# Dagger + MVP - Problems injecting Presenter in Model

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm having problems with the dagger dependency cycle, and despite looking for hours, I can not find the solution. I think it's my idea of architecture. What could be wrong? I'm using Dagger 2.11.

Following the codes

Inicio.java

```
public class Inicio extends BaseFragment implements InicioMvpView {

@Inject
InicioMvpPresenter inicioPresenter;

@Inject
MainMvpPresenter<MainMvpView> mainPresenter;
//...
```

InicioComponent.java

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {InicioModule.class})
public interface InicioComponent extends AndroidInjector<Inicio> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<Inicio> {
    }
}
```

InicioModel.java

```
public class InicioModel implements InicioMvpModel{

    @Inject
    InicioMvpPresenter inicioPresenter;

    @Inject
    public InicioModel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void recuperarAgendamentos() {

        //...

        inicioPresenter.atualizarListaAgendamentos(agendamentos);

    }
}
```

InicioModule.java

```
@Module
public class InicioModule {

    @Provides
    InicioMvpView provideInicioView(Inicio inicioFragment){
        return inicioFragment;
    }

    @Provides
    InicioMvpPresenter provideInicioPresenter(
            InicioPresenter presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

    @Provides
    InicioMvpModel provideInicioModel(InicioModel inicioModel) {
        return inicioModel;
    }
}
```

InicioPresenter.java

```
public class InicioPresenter implements InicioMvpPresenter{

    @Inject
    InicioMvpModel inicioModel;

    @Inject
    InicioMvpView inicioMvpView;

    @Inject
    public InicioPresenter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void recuperarAgendamentos(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //..

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, why are you annotating method this @inject? Are you calling AndroidInjector.inject() in any place?

Comment: Hi, I'm calling in the activity that inflates the fragment.

Comment: I don't think this works. Try to call in the Fragment. Also try to not inject your views, just the make it simpler. Add the views latter. And don't inject your presenter using @Inject in your properties, Inject in the constructor

Comment: Thanks Leandro. Everything is working, until I try to inject the Presenter into the Model, that's the problem.

Comment: I don't see this in the code. So, the Model has an instance of Presenter and Presenter has an instance of Model, right? Are you trying to make Dagger solve this ciclic problem?

Comment: If I try to pass the presenter in the model constructor, does not work, either.

Comment: That, Leandro. My the Model has an instance of Presenter and Presenter has instance of Model.

Comment: Dagger can't inject when you have ciclic dependencies. Like: If Presenter depends on Model and Model depends on Presenter,  which create first?? Dagger can't solve this. But any way... why does Model has a Presenter instance?? You surely don't need this. Just pass callbacks to the model. Or, even better, use RxJava

Comment: So what's the best way to pass the callbacks to the model?

Comment: I guess passing the presenter as a parameter in your method is an OK way to solve this. Check my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you trying to solve a ciclic dependency with Dagger and Dagger doesn't solve this problem.

This can be corrected in your architecture. Just pass a callback to your model instead of passing the Presenter to the Model.

This this:

```
public class InicioModel implements InicioMvpModel{

@Inject
public InicioModel() {

}

@Override
public void recuperarAgendamentos(Presenter inicioPresenter) {

    //...

      inicioPresenter.atualizarListaAgendamentos(agendamentos);

    }
}
```

That's it. Just pass the presenter as a parameter in your methods in your model. This makes the communication less coupled.

You can also take a look for RxJava, it removes the need to pass the presenter in the method. Link: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

There is also a good implementation to follow for MVP by Antonio Leiva: 
https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp

Comment: Thank Leandro, that's exactly it. Lack of attention of mine, maybe for being a beginner with Dagger.